# Angular 4/Ionic 2 Post Request create field `registration` params when sending to Rails 5 API

Tags: angular, ionic2, ruby-on-rails-5

I've an Ionic2/Angular4 App that's have the following method:

```
const body = JSON.stringify(values);
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

console.log(body)

return this.http.post(`${this.url}/auth`, body, {headers: headers})
  .map(response => response.json());
```

The `console.log` prints out this:

```
{"nickname":"rodrigo","email":"rodrigo@email.com","password":"password"}
```

This is JSON is what I expected to `body` to be. But, when the request is done, I receive this output on my Rails log:

```
{"nickname"=>"rodrigo", "email"=>"rodrigo@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "registration"=>{"nickname"=>"rodrigo", "email"=>"rodrigo@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

I can't explain why this field `registration` appear. This not happens when I do the request via Postman.

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit 1

As @Sebastián Palma asked, I added "registration" key as follows:

```
this.signUpForm = this.fb.group({
  'registration[nickname]': ['', Validators.required ],
  'registration[email]': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
  'registration[password]': ['', Validators.required],
  'registration[passwordConfirmation]': ['', Validators.required]
});
```

I got this on Rails log:

```
{
   "registration[nickname]" => "rodrigo", 
   "registration[email]" => "rodrigo@email.com", 
   "registration[password]" => "[FILTERED]",
   "registration[passwordConfirmation]" => "[FILTERED]", 
   "registration" => {
      "registration[nickname]" => "rodrigo", 
      "registration[email]" => "rodrigo@email.com", 
      "registration[password]" => "[FILTERED]",
      "registration[passwordConfirmation]" => "[FILTERED]"
   }
 }
```

#### Edit 2

I just found that two request are made inside Network tab in Chrome. One of them is `POST` and the another one is `OPTION`.

Comment: Nest your body within a "registration" key and try it again, do you get the same response?

Comment: I updated the awnser nesting `registration.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I discovered this is a Rails configuration. I changed `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb` from

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: [:json]
end
```

to this

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: []
end
```

Answer (score 1):

the OPTIONS request is fine, its the preflight to check if POST request is allowed.

If your service only wants the registration object without envelope, just discard the inner formGroup and simple remove the registration[] from your key names, but if service wants envelopehave a form like this:

```
this.signUpForm = this.fb.group({
  registration: this.fb.group({
    nickname: ['', Validators.required ],
    email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.email])],
    password: ['', Validators.required],
    passwordConfirmation: ['', Validators.required],
  })
});
```

You will also need to update your template accordingly, but this should give you the payload you want inside `signUpForm.value` in form of:

```
{
  registration: {
    nickname: 'foo',
    email: 'bar',
    password: 'password',
    passwordConfirmation: 'password'
  }
}
```

Comment: So, this is not the problem. Even with/without the registration[], I got two set of parameters in my requests in Rails log, one with registration key, one without.

Comment: Ok, then i'd check what's hitting the service (devTools network and check the payload that's leaving your app to the service), secondly i'd review the rails service and make sure some code is not generating this.